# Comparison of different algorithms for summing floating point numbers

Tags: floating-point

I am exploring several approaches to summing floating point values, such as:

1. Naive summation, for comparison
2. Summing sorted values
3. summing with numpy, again for comparison
4. [Kahan's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)
5. [Pairwise summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation)
6. Kahan's algorithm on the same sequence sorted by absolute value
7. Pairwise summation on the same sequence sorted by absolute value
8. The Python [Decimal package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html), which is exact.

As shown below, I tested all of these algorithms on 14 arrays of floating point numbers, `not_okay`, from a real world problem.

```python
import numpy as np
from math import floor
from decimal import Decimal

ok = [
    [6.333333333333335, 2.3333333333333335, 2.220446049250313e-16, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0000000000000002, -0.9999999999999999, -4.710277376051324e-16, -0.6666666666666665, -0.6666666666666669, -0.6666666666666669],
    [2.3333333333333335, 6.333333333333334, 2.220446049250313e-16, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -4.710277376051324e-16, -1.0000000000000002, -0.9999999999999999, -0.6666666666666669, -0.6666666666666665, -0.6666666666666669],
    [2.220446049250313e-16, 2.220446049250313e-16, 9.333333333333334, -2.0, -0.9999999999999999, -1.0000000000000002, -0.9999999999999999, -1.0000000000000002, -0.6666666666666669, -0.6666666666666669, -0.6666666666666663],
    [-2.0, 6.333333333333335, -2.3333333333333335, -5.360630966617861e-16, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0000000000000002, 0.9999999999999999, -0.6666666666666665, 0.6666666666666669, 0.6666666666666669, -1.099064721078642e-15, 3.1401849173675484e-16],
    [-2.3333333333333335, 6.333333333333335, -1.1102230246251565e-16, 1.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.710277376051324e-16, 0.6666666666666669, -0.6666666666666665, -0.6666666666666669, -1.0000000000000007, -0.9999999999999996]
]

not_ok = [
    [-2.0, 0.9999999999999999, -1.0000000000000002, 0.9999999999999999, -1.0000000000000002, 0.6666666666666669, 0.6666666666666669, -0.6666666666666663, -3.3306690738754696e-16, -3.3306690738754696e-16, 9.333333333333332, 3.1401849173675503e-16, -2.0, -0.9999999999999997, -1.0000000000000004, -0.9999999999999997, -1.0000000000000004, -0.6666666666666667, -0.6666666666666667, -0.6666666666666667],
    [-0.9999999999999999, -1.0000000000000002, -2.0, -0.6666666666666669, 0.6666666666666669, -0.6666666666666663, 3.1401849173675484e-16, 0.9999999999999996, -1.0000000000000004, 5.551115123125783e-16, -5.551115123125783e-16, 9.333333333333334, 3.1401849173675503e-16, 0.9999999999999997, -1.0000000000000004, -2.0, 0.6666666666666663, -0.6666666666666663, -0.6666666666666677, -0.9999999999999997, -1.0000000000000004],
    [-0.9999999999999999, -1.0000000000000002, 0.6666666666666669, -0.6666666666666669, -0.6666666666666663, -2.0, 0.9999999999999996, 3.1401849173675484e-16, -1.0000000000000004, 3.1401849173675503e-16, -5.551115123125783e-16, 5.551115123125783e-16, 9.333333333333336, 0.9999999999999997, -1.0000000000000004, -0.6666666666666663, 0.6666666666666663, -0.6666666666666677, -2.0, -0.9999999999999997, -1.0000000000000004],
    [-2.0, 0.9999999999999997, -1.0000000000000004, 0.9999999999999997, -1.0000000000000004, 0.6666666666666667, 0.6666666666666667, -0.6666666666666667, -7.771561172376096e-16, -6.661338147750939e-16, 9.333333333333334, -9.420554752102646e-16, -2.0, -0.9999999999999993, -1.0000000000000004, -0.9999999999999993, -1.0000000000000004, -0.6666666666666664, -0.6666666666666664, -0.6666666666666667],
    [-0.9999999999999997, -1.0000000000000004, -2.0, -0.6666666666666663, 0.6666666666666663, -0.6666666666666677, 0.9999999999999997, -1.0000000000000004, -3.625639149961434e-15, 2.9976021664879227e-15, 9.33333333333333, -9.420554752102646e-16, 1.0000000000000018, -0.999999999999998, -2.0, 0.6666666666666673, -0.6666666666666673, -0.666666666666665, 6.2803698347351125e-16, -1.0000000000000018, -0.999999999999998],
    [-0.9999999999999997, -1.0000000000000004, 0.6666666666666663, -0.6666666666666663, -0.6666666666666677, -2.0, 0.9999999999999997, -1.0000000000000004, -9.420554752102646e-16, 2.9976021664879227e-15, -3.6637359812630166e-15, 9.33333333333333, 1.0000000000000018, -0.999999999999998, -0.6666666666666673, 0.6666666666666673, -0.666666666666665, -2.0, -1.0000000000000018, 6.2803698347351125e-16, -0.999999999999998],
    [-0.6666666666666667, -0.6666666666666667, -0.6666666666666667, -0.9999999999999997, -1.0000000000000004, -0.9999999999999997, -1.0000000000000004, -2.0, -9.420554752102646e-16, -3.181549940111371e-15, -3.219646771412954e-15, 9.333333333333329, 0.6666666666666673, 0.6666666666666673, -0.666666666666665, 6.2803698347351125e-16, 1.0000000000000018, -0.999999999999998, 1.0000000000000018, 6.2803698347351125e-16, -0.999999999999998, -2.0],
    [-2.0, 1.0000000000000018, -0.999999999999998, 1.0000000000000018, -0.999999999999998, 0.6666666666666673, 0.6666666666666673, -0.666666666666665, -9.992007221626409e-16, -8.881784197001252e-16, 9.333333333333325, -9.420554752102646e-16, -2.0, -1.0000000000000018, -0.999999999999998, -1.0000000000000018, -0.999999999999998, -0.6666666666666664, -0.6666666666666664, -0.6666666666666667],
    [-0.9999999999999993, -1.0000000000000004, -2.0, -0.6666666666666673, 0.6666666666666673, -0.666666666666665, 6.2803698347351125e-16, 1.0000000000000018, -0.999999999999998, -1.703431368239316e-15, 1.7763568394002505e-15, 9.333333333333323, -9.420554752102646e-16, 1.0000000000000018, -0.999999999999998, -2.0, 0.6666666666666664, -0.6666666666666664, -0.6666666666666667, -6.280369834735128e-16, -1.0000000000000044, -0.9999999999999954],
    [-0.9999999999999993, -1.0000000000000004, 0.6666666666666673, -0.6666666666666673, -0.666666666666665, -2.0, 1.0000000000000018, 6.2803698347351125e-16, -0.999999999999998, -9.420554752102646e-16, 1.7763568394002505e-15, -1.5543122344752192e-15, 9.333333333333325, 1.0000000000000018, -0.999999999999998, -0.6666666666666664, 0.6666666666666664, -0.6666666666666667, -2.0, -1.0000000000000044, -6.280369834735128e-16, -0.9999999999999954],
    [-2.0, 1.0000000000000018, -0.999999999999998, 1.0000000000000018, -0.999999999999998, 0.6666666666666664, 0.6666666666666664, -0.6666666666666667, 1.2212453270876722e-15, 1.1102230246251565e-15, 9.333333333333321, 4.082240392577823e-15, -2.0, -1.0000000000000024, -0.999999999999998, -1.0000000000000024, -0.999999999999998, -0.6666666666666671, -0.6666666666666671, -0.6666666666666667],
    [-1.0000000000000018, -0.999999999999998, -2.0, -0.6666666666666664, 0.6666666666666664, -0.6666666666666667, -6.280369834735128e-16, 1.0000000000000044, -0.9999999999999954, 4.440892098500626e-15, -6.5503158452884236e-15, 9.333333333333329, 4.082240392577823e-15, 0.9999999999999974, -1.0000000000000029, -2.0, 0.6666666666666671, -0.6666666666666671, -0.6666666666666667, -0.9999999999999974, -1.0000000000000029],
    [-1.0000000000000018, -0.999999999999998, 0.6666666666666664, -0.6666666666666664, -0.6666666666666667, -2.0, 1.0000000000000044, -6.280369834735128e-16, -0.9999999999999954, 4.082240392577823e-15, -6.5503158452884236e-15, 4.3298697960381105e-15, 9.33333333333333, 0.9999999999999974, -1.0000000000000029, -0.6666666666666671, 0.6666666666666671, -0.6666666666666667, -2.0, -0.9999999999999974, -1.0000000000000029],
    [-0.6666666666666664, -0.6666666666666664, -0.6666666666666667, -6.280369834735128e-16, -1.0000000000000044, -0.9999999999999954, -1.0000000000000044, -6.280369834735128e-16, -0.9999999999999954, -2.0, 4.082240392577823e-15, 2.1094237467877974e-15, 1.9984014443252818e-15, 9.333333333333316, 0.6666666666666671, 0.6666666666666671, -0.6666666666666667, 1.0000000000000024, -0.999999999999998, 1.0000000000000024, -0.999999999999998, -2.0]
]

# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm
def kahan_summation(x):
    result = 0.0
    c = 0.0

    for x_ in x:
        y = x_ - c
        t = result + y
        c = (t - result) - y
        result = t

    return result

# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation
def pairwise_summation(x):
    if len(x) <= 2:
        return sum(x)
    else:
        m = floor(len(x)/2)
        return pairwise_summation(x[:m]) + pairwise_summation(x[m:])

def summation_algorithms(data):
    print("{:>24} {:>24} {:>24} {:>24} {:>24} {:>24} {:>24} {:>24}".format("naive sum", "sum sorted values", "numpy sum", "kahan sum", "pairwise sum", "kahan sum sorted", "pairwise sum sorted", "Decimal sum"))

    for values in data:
        sorted_values = sorted(values, key = lambda x_: abs(x_))

        naive_sum = sum(values)
        sum_sorted_values = sum(sorted_values)
        numpy_sum = np.sum(np.array(values))
        kahan_sum = kahan_summation(values)
        pairwise_sum = pairwise_summation(values)
        decimal_sum = sum([Decimal(str(x_)) for x_ in values])
        pairwise_sum_sorted = pairwise_summation(sorted_values)
        kahan_sum_sorted = kahan_summation(sorted_values)

        print("{:24} {:24} {:24} {:24} {:24} {:24} {:24} {:24}".format(naive_sum, sum_sorted_values, numpy_sum, kahan_sum, pairwise_sum, kahan_sum_sorted, pairwise_sum_sorted, decimal_sum))


#summation_algorithms(ok)
summation_algorithms(not_ok)
```

Result (row-wise)

```
               naive sum        sum sorted values                numpy sum                kahan sum             pairwise sum         kahan sum sorted      pairwise sum sorted              Decimal sum
 -2.4424906541753444e-15                      0.0   -6.661338147750939e-16  -1.9984014443252818e-15  -1.5543122344752192e-15  -1.7763568394002505e-15  -1.7763568394002505e-15      -1.752115323039E-15
  -1.887379141862766e-15  -1.7763568394002505e-15                      0.0  -1.3322676295501878e-15                      0.0  -1.7763568394002505e-15  -1.3322676295501878e-15      -1.071963016526E-15
  1.7763568394002505e-15                      0.0                      0.0                      0.0   1.7763568394002505e-15                      0.0    4.440892098500626e-16        9.28036983474E-16
 -2.7755575615628914e-15  -1.7763568394002505e-15  -2.7755575615628914e-15  -2.6645352591003757e-15   -3.552713678800501e-15  -1.7763568394002505e-15  -2.6645352591003757e-15      -1.985345407223E-15
  -6.661338147750939e-16                      0.0   -2.220446049250313e-16    4.440892098500626e-16  -1.7763568394002505e-15                      0.0    2.220446049250313e-16       -4.42055475209E-16
  -8.881784197001252e-16                      0.0   -8.881784197001252e-16   -4.440892098500626e-16   1.7763568394002505e-15                      0.0    2.220446049250313e-16      -4.801523065115E-16
 -1.9984014443252818e-15  -1.7763568394002505e-15  -1.1102230246251565e-15                      0.0                      0.0                      0.0                      0.0       -1.87178219786E-16
 -1.1102230246251565e-16                      0.0   3.3306690738754696e-16                      0.0   -4.440892098500626e-16                      0.0    8.881784197001252e-16        2.70565382927E-16
 -1.2212453270876722e-15  -1.7763568394002505e-15  -2.1094237467877974e-15   -1.887379141862766e-15  -2.6645352591003757e-15  -1.7763568394002505e-15  -1.3322676295501878e-15      -1.469130004049E-15
  -5.551115123125783e-16                      0.0   1.2212453270876722e-15    7.771561172376096e-16    8.881784197001252e-16                      0.0    6.661338147750939e-16       6.799891297155E-16
  -7.771561172376096e-16                      0.0    -2.55351295663786e-15   -4.440892098500626e-16   -8.881784197001252e-16                      0.0   -4.440892098500626e-16       -5.86291255709E-16
   6.661338147750939e-16                      0.0   -6.661338147750939e-16   -4.440892098500626e-16   -8.881784197001252e-16                      0.0   -8.881784197001252e-16        3.44779662317E-16
  2.4424906541753444e-15   1.7763568394002505e-15   1.5543122344752192e-15   1.7763568394002505e-15   2.6645352591003757e-15   1.7763568394002505e-15    8.881784197001252e-16       1.233757359854E-15
                     0.0                      0.0    8.881784197001252e-16    4.440892098500626e-16   -8.881784197001252e-16                      0.0    2.220446049250313e-16        1.33991616743E-16
```

Disappointingly Kahan's method does not seem to work well. In fact no other method consistently agrees with the "Decimal sum".

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to approach this problem?

---

As a sanity check of my implementations I provided five arrays of "unproblematic" floating numbers `okay` the sum of which is given below

```
               naive sum        sum sorted values                numpy sum                kahan sum             pairwise sum         kahan sum sorted      pairwise sum sorted              Decimal sum
      0.6666666666666671       0.6666666666666687       0.6666666666666671       0.6666666666666677        0.666666666666667       0.6666666666666679       0.6666666666666679 0.666666666666667851016867320
      0.6666666666666666       0.6666666666666679       0.6666666666666666       0.6666666666666673        0.666666666666667        0.666666666666667       0.6666666666666679 0.666666666666666851016867320
      1.3333333333333337        1.333333333333334       1.3333333333333337        1.333333333333334        1.333333333333334        1.333333333333334       1.3333333333333344 1.333333333333334144089209850
      2.6666666666666674        2.666666666666667       2.6666666666666674        2.666666666666667       2.6666666666666674        2.666666666666667        2.666666666666668 2.666666666666667178890673996
     -0.6666666666666654      -0.6666666666666652      -0.6666666666666654      -0.6666666666666663      -0.6666666666666652      -0.6666666666666661      -0.6666666666666659 -0.666666666666665882050040068
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is let the input arrays `ok` and `not_ok` consist of strings, otherwise there's already a possible conversion error going **to** `Decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

Kahan’s algorithm calculates a+b and the exact rounding error if |a| >= |b|. Actually for a slightly larger range of values. So for a sum of array elements, if the sum so far is always absolutely greater than the next array element, then Kahan calculates simultaneously the naive sum, and the naive sum of the exact rounding errors. The sum of rounding errors will have a very small error because the numbers added are small. So adding the naive sum and the sum of rounding errors will very often give the correctly rounded result.

Exceptions are: If the sum of the numbers as real numbers is quite precisely between two floating point numbers, and instead of rounding by 0.4999999999 bits in one direction the result is rounded by 0.500000001 bits in the other direction. And the other situation, if the sum is much smaller than the original numbers. Worst case the correct sum is smaller than the individual rounding errors.

And of course the big exception: If the first operand had a smaller absolute value during the summation. That’s easy to fix: if |a| < |b| then calculate b+a instead (same as a+b obviously) but calculate the rounding error for b+a which will then be correct.

None of these methods will guarantee a correctly rounded sum. All you can do is keep the error smaller.

Comment: I am looking at the implementation of `msum` on this [page](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/393090/). It is based on this  [paper](http://www-2.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/quake/public/papers/robust-arithmetic.ps) but I cannot find the description in the paper.